# Need a batch file to copy new and changed files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy files from one location to another location, but only copy new files, or files that have changed.

For instance, I have data in C:\Working which includes folders and files.  The files are changed, and removed from there as they are no longer needed or a project is complete.

I need a batch file to move everything in that location to D:\Storage.  Since some files may not have changed, I do not want to copy those, however, I do want to copy and replace files that have been modified.

I believe I can use Robocopy /E and that will give me the recursion that I need.  I am not sure on how to check hashes or stamps to verify if the file has been changed.  I know I can EXCLUDE files with the /XC, but I think that's the opposite of what I want.

Right now my file as as folows:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Working
>nul Robocopy /E . D:\Storage
popd
```

Edit:  I don't want to just copy everything because the working location may have upwards of 60GB in it, and only 1-2GB needs to be copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

> By default Robocopy will only copy a file if the source and destination have different time stamps or different file sizes.

Therefore, `Robocopy . D:\Storage /E` should be fine.  You may want to add the `/XO` option depending on what you want.